# HttpReqeust not found but I real installed pecl_http

Tags: php, pecl

I'm use php-fpm on centos, php version is 5.5.6

When I install pecl_http and restart fpm, I get the phpinfo abot pecl_http module:

> **http**
>
> HTTP Support  enabled Extension Version   2.0.1
>
> Used Library  Compiled    Linked libz 1.2.7   1.2.7 libcurl   7.29.0  7.29.0
>   libevent  disabled    disabled
>
> Directive Local Value Master Value http.etag.mode crc32b  crc32b
>
> **propro**
>
> Property proxy support    enabled Extension version   1.0.0
>
> **raphf**
>
> Resource and persistent handle factory support    enabled Extension
>   version   1.0.4
>
> Persistent handles in this process Provider   Ident   Used    Free
>
> Directive Local Value Master Value raphf.persistent_handle.limit  -1  -1

It's look fine that pecl_http are success installed.(I load 3 so lib: http.so propro.so  raphf.so)
But I always get a HttpRequest or same class HttpMessage class not found error In CLI or Web page.

Please tell me how can find the reason.

Comment: you should post the extension=modulex.so portion of your php.ini file.  Also run php --ini from command line to see what modules are being loaded.  Also post the exact error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stable pecl_http is now at version 2, which provides `http\Client` and `http\Message`, etc:
http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http

If you want `HttpRequest` and `HttpMessage`, that is v1, which you have to install explicitly:

`$ pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6`